# referencing variable in document class from another class

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to increment an integer variable in a function within the document class upon transpiring event in another class. I can't seem to figure out how to call the function  and reference the variable.

as3 newbie, please help!

Comment: please provide some sample code

Comment: A lot of the answers for this question suggest using a public static property/method to access the document class's members. The issue with this is that although it allows the DocumentClass's members to be accessed globally, therein lies the potential security concern, it can accessed globally. It maybe a better idea to parse a reference of the document class to your other class, so access is only subject to said class. Then again this introduces the new issue of "tight-coupling".

Comment: If I'm reading the question right, event dispatching probably would have been a way to avoid a Singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper scope needs to be in place and the proper packaging.

Declare a static variable to handle your access to the Main Document Class

```
private static var _instance:Main;
public static function get instance():Main { return _instance; }

public function Main() { // constructor
    _instance = this;
}
```

Declare some getters and setters in the Main Document Class

```
private var _foo:int = 0;

public function get foo():int{
    return _foo;
}

public function set foo(value:int):void {
    _foo= value;
}
```

And then in any class you need you can change to something as follows,

```
public class O {
    public function O() {
        Main.instance.set(Main.instance.get() + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple example, defining a variable 'test' in the document class:

```
package {   
    public class DocumentClass extends Sprite {
        public static var test:Number = 3;      
        public function DocumentClass() {
            test = 4;
        }            
    }
}
```

now access the 'test' variable in another class:

```
package {   
    public class OtherClass extends Sprite {
        public function OtherClass() {          
            DocumentClass.test = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

does this apply to your code?